# Why does importing the GPG key for the mono repo fail?

Tags: mono

When following the steps to setup mono on the following site it is failing to import the GPG key for the repo.

https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-centos

This is happening on CentOS machines running both 6.x and 7.x.

rpm --import "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF"

error: https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF: key 1 not an armored public key.

Answer (score -2):

This appears to be due to a missing newline at the end of the key file. If you open the key with vi and save it, without making any changes (this is one way to ensure there is a newline at the end of the file), the import works.

```
curl -v "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF" -okey
vi key
# don't modify, just save it with ":wq"
rpm --import key
```

Another way to add the newline to the end of the file: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31955

```
sed -i -e '$a\' key
```

see https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/15955

Answer (score -3):

I used this workaround to then download.  See https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/16025

```
rpm --import https://download.mono-project.com/repo/xamarin.gpg
```

```
su -c 'curl https://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos7-stable.repo | tee /etc/yum.repos.d/mono-centos7-stable.repo’
```